# AKMicrophoneTracker. frequency is not accurate (AudioKit 4.10.1)

Tags: audiokit

```
let tracker = AKMicrophoneTracker()
tracker.start()
...
tracker.frequency
```

the frequency is different from the real sound, for example, I play E4(329.6hz) on my guitar, but tracker.frequency is about 300hz